# Sed comment printf statements

Tags: regex, sed

I tried to comment all printf statements in all files from a directory in the following manner:

```
sed -i 's/\ printf/\ \/\/printf/g' *

sed -i 's/ printf/ \/\/printf/g' *
```

Unfortunatelly, these approaches did not work.

I relied on what I know from vim substitute regex.

I know I should have used a macro for this task, but for now I just need a fast solution.

Comment: Can you show your sample input file?

Comment: I don't think that's relevant. The files are just regular C source code files.

Comment: A sample of your input *is* relevant. Please also describe what the output should like and in which cases you *don't* want the substitution to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a programming language that provides you with options for enabling and disabling a piece of code.  Rather than manipulating the sources, make use of a `#define` to enable/disable `printf` statements.

Replace all `printf`s, e.g.

```
printf("Some value %d", val);
```

with

```
if (TOPRINT) printf("Some value %d", val);
```

which is a trivial `s|printf|if (TOPRINT) &|` *one-time* replacement.

While compiling your code, if you want `printf`s to be enabled, say:

```
gcc -DTOPRINT foo.c
```

No need to make any subsequent modifications to the source for commenting/uncommenting the `printf` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a cludgy hack to modify the source code with sed, I recommend to use a proper, powerful tool specifically made to make code transformations like that,
[Coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/).

It is very simple to do what you describe as a proper solution by using a macro:

```
$ spatch --sp-file test.cocci test.c
init_defs_builtins: /usr/share/coccinelle/standard.h
HANDLING: test.c
diff = 
--- test.c
+++ /tmp/cocci-output-27579-c89047-test.c
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@

 void f(void)
 {
-       printf("hello\n");
+       MY_PRINTF_MACRO("hello\n");
        real_work();
-       printf("goodbye\n");
+       MY_PRINTF_MACRO("goodbye\n");
 }
$
```

with a test.cocci file containing:

```
@@
@@
-   printf
+   MY_PRINTF_MACRO
    (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's|^ *printf|\/\/&|' *
```

could do part of you ask by commenting line that start with printf with eventually some space before but it's a bit special cause printf could appear everywhere on a line like after a then/else or simply other instruction of if on the same line `//` comment the follwing instruction also (if not  commenting from start of line but just before `printf`) so, maybe other way could be better